# Exporting links in google scholar results

Tags: google-scholar

I want to export data from google scholar.  In particular, I want to export a list of articles that cite a particular paper.   If I click the `Cited By` link I can get this page.  One way I can export these data is to add all of them to my library. Then you can export in 4 different formats (BibTex, Refman, Endnote, CSV).  However, none of these export formats include the HTML link (URL) to each paper.

The other strategy would be to scrape the data, but I don't want to do that as I know that this can be very tricky with google scholar's captchas.

Is there a way to export the results of a google scholar search that includes the URLs of each paper ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the page you're on you mean? From the console (F12) do:

```
copy($$('li > a').map(a => a.href))
```

Now they're in your clipboard.

Comment: actually - as a follow up - this doesn't quite look to be working.  The list of urls that I generate all redirect to the "cited by" page for each article I try this on.  It doesn't give me the unique urls of each paper on that page.

Comment: I'm not sure what page you're looking at, you might have to adjust the `li > a` part. Just `a` will give you all links on the page.

Comment: thanks, replacing with `a` does get closer, but copies everything on the page.   e.g. here is a page:  `https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=5,44&sciodt=0,44&as_ylo=2017&cites=12057671250163316206&scipsc=&q=`  I'm just trying to get the 10 urls of each paper on this page.

Comment: As there are multiple other links on the page other than the 10 paper titles, it seems that it's a case of trying to get the urls for all `h3` of the class `gr_rt`

Comment: It looks like `h3 > a` is what you want there

Comment: thanks! I tried every combination but not that one!

Answer (score 1):

To extract `Cited by` data, you'll need an ID of a Google Scholar organic search result that the `Cited by` link belongs to. You can find the ID inside `data-cid` html attribute.

[image]

You can then query the next link to retrieve the data:  `https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=info: this_is_where_you_put_the_cite_id:scholar.google.com/&output=cite`

There is also a third party solution like SerpApi to do this for you. It's a paid API with a free trial.

Example python code (available in other libraries also):

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "engine": "google_scholar_cite",
  "q": "FDc6HiktlqEJ",
  "api_key": "secret_api_key",
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()
```

Example JSON output:

```json
"citations": [
  {
    "title": "MLA",
    "snippet": "Schwertmann, U. T. R. M., and Reginald M. Taylor. \"Iron oxides.\" Minerals in soil environments 1 (1989): 379-438."
  },
  {
    "title": "APA",
    "snippet": "Schwertmann, U. T. R. M., & Taylor, R. M. (1989). Iron oxides. Minerals in soil environments, 1, 379-438."
  },
  {
    "title": "Chicago",
    "snippet": "Schwertmann, U. T. R. M., and Reginald M. Taylor. \"Iron oxides.\" Minerals in soil environments 1 (1989): 379-438."
  },
  {
    "title": "Harvard",
    "snippet": "Schwertmann, U.T.R.M. and Taylor, R.M., 1989. Iron oxides. Minerals in soil environments, 1, pp.379-438."
  },
  {
    "title": "Vancouver",
    "snippet": "Schwertmann UT, Taylor RM. Iron oxides. Minerals in soil environments. 1989 Jan 1;1:379-438."
  }
],
"links": [
  {
    "name": "BibTeX",
    "link": "https://scholar.googleusercontent.com/scholar.bib?q=info:FDc6HiktlqEJ:scholar.google.com/&output=citation&scisdr=CgXpniNQGAA:AAGBfm0AAAAAYMu3WkYJI4po_pgcUVKgwwFp1dl5uNYk&scisig=AAGBfm0AAAAAYMu3WlZR_joxo-i8FTZ1CphjzmW_d447&scisf=4&ct=citation&cd=-1&hl=en"
  },
  {
    "name": "EndNote",
    "link": "https://scholar.googleusercontent.com/scholar.enw?q=info:FDc6HiktlqEJ:scholar.google.com/&output=citation&scisdr=CgXpniNQGAA:AAGBfm0AAAAAYMu3WkYJI4po_pgcUVKgwwFp1dl5uNYk&scisig=AAGBfm0AAAAAYMu3WlZR_joxo-i8FTZ1CphjzmW_d447&scisf=3&ct=citation&cd=-1&hl=en"
  },
  {
    "name": "RefMan",
    "link": "https://scholar.googleusercontent.com/scholar.ris?q=info:FDc6HiktlqEJ:scholar.google.com/&output=citation&scisdr=CgXpniNQGAA:AAGBfm0AAAAAYMu3WkYJI4po_pgcUVKgwwFp1dl5uNYk&scisig=AAGBfm0AAAAAYMu3WlZR_joxo-i8FTZ1CphjzmW_d447&scisf=2&ct=citation&cd=-1&hl=en"
  },
  {
    "name": "RefWorks",
    "link": "https://scholar.googleusercontent.com/scholar.rfw?q=info:FDc6HiktlqEJ:scholar.google.com/&output=citation&scisdr=CgXpniNQGAA:AAGBfm0AAAAAYMu3WkYJI4po_pgcUVKgwwFp1dl5uNYk&scisig=AAGBfm0AAAAAYMu3WlZR_joxo-i8FTZ1CphjzmW_d447&scisf=1&ct=citation&cd=-1&hl=en"
  }
]
```

Check out the [documentation](https://serpapi.com/google-scholar-cite-api) for more details.

*Disclaimer: I work at SerpApi.*